# What's the difference between message_filters and image_transport?

Tags: message-filters, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using ROS Fuerte. I need to subscribe to 2 streams from the Kinect (color and depth) and use these to get 3D features. I understand to get the 2D feature I can use OpenCv and then relate this to the depth.

I have come across the link
//wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages which has

16 image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
17 image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;

....

23 image_pub_ = it_.advertise("out", 1);
24 image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("in", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);

and the link

//wiki.ros.org/message_filters which has

19 message_filters::Subscriber image1_sub(nh, "image1", 1);
20 message_filters::Subscriber image2_sub(nh, "image2", 1);

Am I correct in saying in order to call both topics in one callback I have to synchronize the streams ?

using something like ApproximateTime Policy under 7.2 ?

Is it necessary to use both message_filters and image_transport ?

And if so how then do I declare the subscribers ?

What is the difference between message_filters and image_transport ?

Sorry for the confusion.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86781/what%27s-the-difference-between-message_filters-and-image_transport?/) by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2013-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`message_filters` and `image_transport` are two separate ROS packages. Each provides several *nodes* which can be used in your configuration. In general, `message_filters` nodes are about filtering or coordinating message deliver, no matter the content of the messages, while `image_transport` nodes are concerned with manipulating the content of the messages.

To process the RGB and depth image together I've used two different strategies:

1. Use a `TimeSynchronizer` message filter to coordinate the two different messages and call a single callback expecting both images. This is probably the best way. The downside is that there is a delay in `TimeSynchronizer` to pair up the most appropriate messages, which can delay processing of whichever image you want to make the highest priority.
2. Have two callbacks, one for each message type. For one, say the depth callback, just save the frame away. In the RGB callback, process the RGB image with the most recent depth frame. The disadvantage here is that if the depth image usually precedes the associated RGB, but occasionally follows it, then you could process a stale depth image. The advantage, however, is that you process the RGB image as soon as it is received. (And you can process both when you receive the depth image instead, if you like.)

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0